# Why does creating a PHP array that is tab delimited results in double entries?

Tags: php, excel, file-handling

Here is my php code for creating a php array that is tab delimited.  It creates an array with double entries (redundancies for each entry in the array).

The array populates the excel sheet properly.  In this case the array $setData has double the values from the SQL query.

```
$setRec = $db->query("SELECT first_name, last_name, zipcode, email, 
dob, graduationYear, educationLevel, gender, gpa, highSchool, 
intendedTransfer, occupation FROM users;");

$columnHeader = '';
$columnHeader = "First Name" . "\t" . "Last Name" . "\t" . "Zipcode" . 
"\t" . "Email" . "\t" . "Date of Birth" . "\t" . "Graduation Year" . 
"\t" . "Education Level" . "\t" . "Gender" . "\t" . "GPA" . "\t" . 
"High School" . "\t" . "Intended Transfer" . "\t" . "Occupation" . "\t";

$setData = '';

while ($rec = $setRec->fetch()) {
    $rowData = '';
    foreach ($rec as $value) {
    $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
    $rowData .= $value;
}

// echo $rowData;
// $rowData = '"' . $rec[1] . '"' . "\t".'"' . $rec[2] . '"' . "\t".'"' . $rec[3] . '"' . "\t".'"' . $rec[5] . '"' . "\t".'"' . $rec[8] . '"' . "\t".'"' . $rec[9] . '"' . "\t".'"' . $rec[10] . '"' . "\t".'"' . $rec[11] . '"' . "\t".'"' . $rec[12] . '"' . "\t".'"' . $rec[13] . '"' . "\t".'"' . $rec[14] . '"' . "\t".'"' . $rec[17] . '"' . "\t".'"' . $rec[18] . '"' . "\t";
$setData .= $rowData . "\n";
}


header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; 
filename=User_Detail_Report.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

echo ucwords($columnHeader) . "\n" . $setData . "\n";
```

Comment: What database API are you using?

Comment: Looks like you run the default fetch mode (`MYSQLI_BOTH` or `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`)

Comment: @AbraCadaver Apologies, i'm not sure what you were asking specifically but I am using PDO to connect with the database, but besides that everything seen here is the only code used to get data and populate the excel sheet.

Comment: @Dormilich how would you suggest he fix the problem. Would he use another API?

Comment: @Mustafa First he should check which fetch mode he's using.